# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a populate script which I put together from the tango_with_django tutorial (https://github.com/leifos/tango_with_django/blob/master/tango_with_django_project/populate_rango.py) however I'm getting the below traceback and it seems to be related to changes made in Django 1.7? I'd appreciate if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong here.

```
(test_env) C:\Users\WriteCode\test_env\epl>python populate_clubs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_clubs.py", line 4, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 20, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 46, in __ge
tattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 40, in _set
up
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, b
ut settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

(test_env) C:\Users\WriteCode\test_env\epl>
```

My populate_clubs.py script

```
import os
import sys
import django
django.setup()


def add_club(name, nickname, manager, established, stadium, active=True):
    c = clubs.objects.get_or_create(name=name, nickname=nickname, manager=manager, established=established, stadium=stadium, active=active)
    return c

def populate():
    add_club(name = "Aston Villa",
        nickname = "Villans",
        manager = "Tim Sherwood",
        established = "1897",
        stadium = "Villa Park"
        )

    # Print out what was added
    for c in clubs.objects.all():
        print "The following has been added to clubs:" + c



# Start execution
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting club population script..."
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'epl.settings')
    from teams.models import clubs
    populate()
```

Comment: Using a management command might be the easiest way to interact with django using a script

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Call to `django.setup()` should go after setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable. Just move it into your `__main__` right after `os.environ.setdefault()`.

Answer (score 36):

You can insert `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")` before the `django.setup()` line.

Comment: I ran into this same issue using PyCharm (version 2017.2.3) as my IDE.  To fix this is PyCharm, you need to go to `PyCharm -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Django Console`.  Then enter `os.environ.setdefault(...)` into the `Starting script` window.

Comment: In `PyCharm -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Django Console` there's a dedicated button to set `Environment variables`. Open it and add `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` = `some_project.settings`

Answer (score 14):

If you are getting a similar error after initiating your interaction with Django by running `python` in a terminal, running `python manage.py shell` in the appropriate directory may solve your issue.

Comment: I forgot Django has its own interactive shell. This solved it for me!

Comment: Why would that help?

Answer (score 2):

For development and debugging, you may use the [standalone](https://github.com/biwin/standalone) python package.

Install with pip

```
pip install standalone
```

Use standalone to use Django from the module.

```
# add the following to the top of the module.
import standalone
standalone.run('mysite.settings') # replace with your settings module.

# your code goes below the configuration
import os
import sys

# ... .. .  whole module
```

Now you may run the module as a Python Django script.

Answer (score 1):

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'epl.settings')
```

should be above

```
import django
```

which is you should call django_settings_module before importing and calling django setup.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running **PyCharm**, what worked for me was to invalidate the cache and restart the app.

`File => Invalidate Caches / Restart ...`

My virtualenv had been recently updated from Python 3.6 or 3.7 to 3.8.

Comment: this did not work for me at least

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I used django related import statement in a non-django module.
i.e `from index.views import view` that did raise an error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when setting the environment.

(I tried to add the:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")
```

into the "Starting script window",which is in the Django Console or rewrite the .wsgi file, But all of them were failed)

My final solution: (open the terminal and set the environment manually)

Here are the steps:(for mac)

1. open the terminal and type vim ~/.bash_profile
2. add below lines:

   ```
    PATH=${PATH}:/Users/work/workspace/[virtual_environment]/bin
    PYTHONPATH=${PATH}:/Users/work/PycharmProjects/[project_name]
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=[project_name].settings
   ```
3. type :wq to save and exit terminal
4. type source ~/.bash_profile to reload it

it will work when you run `python manage.py` shell this time.

Comment: Would this work on a production environment, or just on a local development machine?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to activate your venv first by scripts/activate venv then in your populate_user.py right after *import os* run *os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'epl.settings')* this should work.