# How to fix the ImproperlyConfigured exception?

Tags: django, django-settings

I listen to a video that explains how to do login API to Facebook now I installed the allauth lib by pip3 and placed it into INSTALLED_APPS and I did create AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS and all the initializations of allauth lib to handle it and when I do migrate to apps I was show error that defines that I should put django.setup() and I did fix it now I receive the next Trace:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/ripo/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/ripo/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/ripo/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

so how can I fix this issue?

Comment: please refer to this question, it might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525825/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-requested-setting-logging-config-b/41110024

Comment: this question has passed on me when I do a search for this issue but it didn't help me